# PhoneGap with Blackberry - why isn't "date" input type giving a datepicker?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, datepicker, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to use the 'date' type for an input field in a PhoneGap application. It works on iOS and Android devices, but Blackberry treats it like a regular input field.

It's my understanding that Blackberry supports the "date" input type.
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/html_input_types_1247751_11.html

I've tried dozens of ways of structuring the HTML, including removing all JS/CSS and making the app only one line:

```
<input type='date' class='submission-field date' name='my_date' />
```

I've tried many variations of this line, including:

```
<input type="date" id="txtDate"  min="2010-01-01" max="2018-12-31" value=""/>
```

When I create a webpage with this line of code and visit it on the Blackberry device's browser, it correctly opens a native date picker. So it works in the browser, but not in PhoneGap application.

I've also updated Blackberry to the latest software.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, or if this is just impossible and I'm misunderstanding the capabilities of PhoneGap?

Comment: Are you using any framework that transforms markup for UI styling (like jQuery Mobile, or bootstrap?)

Comment: Nope.. I'm putting no CSS or JavaScript on the page. Just a blank HTML document with that input element